# Plotting raster with thresholds in R

Tags: r, plot, raster

I want to plot population data. The data is raster data. The map should have red areas where less than 1 person lives, and another color for areas with more than one person. If I just use the `plot()` function I cannot achieve it. My data comes from: http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev10
Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
library(raster)

myColorRamp <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))

popRaster <- raster("path/to/my/raster")

values(popRaster) <- as.numeric(values(popRaster) >= 1)

plot(popRaster, col=myColorRamp(2))
```

You need to install the `raster` package, which I believe has the `sp` package as a dependency (and possibly `rgdal`).

Answer (score 2):

There are many similar questions like that and a lot of answers, but maybe these 2 options might help.

```
library(raster)

## Create random raster
spg <- data.frame( x = rep( 0:1, each=2 ),
                  y = rep( 0:1,  2),
                  l = c(0.8,1,1.1,100));
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y
gridded(spg) <- TRUE
rasterDF <- raster(spg)

## Assign values, based on your condition
values(rasterDF) <- as.numeric(values(rasterDF) >= 1)

## Create a Color Function
cpal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))

## Plot with raster-package
plot(rasterDF, col=cpal(2))

## Plot with rasterVis package
library(rasterVis)
r2 <- ratify(rasterDF)
levelplot(r2, col.regions=cpal, att='ID')
```